# Select() still blocks read from pipe

Tags: c, io, fork, ipc, pipe

My application forks a child, the child execls a new program, the parent writes to it, and then reads back from the child after the child performs some work.  When monitoring the read end of the pipe, the program still waits for the child.  I'm currently not writing back to the parent, so it intentionally would block. Below is the code (the write_to() function closes the unused parts of the pipe in the function):

```
    pid_t leaf_proc;


    int rv = 0;

    int w_pfd[2];
    int r_pfd[2];   

    if(pipe(w_pfd) == -1 || pipe(r_pfd) == -1){
        printf("Failed to pipe. Goodbye.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if((leaf_proc = fork()) < 0){
        printf("Error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }else if(leaf_proc == 0){
        /***Child to be execl()'d***/
        rv = execl("Some program");
        if(rv < 0){
            printf("Error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        }
    }else{
        /***Parent***/
        write_to(par_info,w_pfd);
        fd_set read_set;
        //struct timeval tv;
        //tv.tv_sec = 5;
        //tv.tv_usec = 0;

        FD_ZERO(&read_set);
        FD_SET(r_pfd[0], &read_set);
        rv = select(r_pfd[0]+1,&read_set,NULL,NULL,&tv);
        printf("set?: %d\n",rv);
     }
```

When running this, the program still hangs at the select statement (last printf is never reached), but if I add timeout info, the program continues after 5 seconds. First of all, am I using select correctly?  And second, while this may not be blocking (in the sense that the parent process won't be interrupted by the kernel, doesn't it still result in the outcome (process hanging until something is ready)?

Comment: well for one, you need to make a master copy of `&read_set` because if you read the manual on `select()` you will see that it modifies the list of FDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to close the unused parts of the pipe in both the child and in the parent process.

After terminating the write fd of the pipe will be closed in the child process, but in the parent it is still open, so your `select` will patiently wait for data....

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear but the write_to() function takes care of closing the read end of the pipes, as does the write_to function in the child process.  If select waits for data, isn't this essentially blocking, just not by putting the process to sleep?

Comment: 1) There's no `write_to` in the child process.... 2) It's like sleeping, while select blocks, the process won't use the CPU.

Comment: The child process execl's a program that does call write_to

Comment: DO YOU close the write end of the pipe in the parent?

Comment: Yes, I've written functions called write_to() and read_from() that handle closing the proper ends of the pipes.

Comment: In that case you would see the printf. So you're not doing it right.. Why don't you show the code??

Comment: Actually, I didn't include the call to write in the child program, because I want the read call in the parent to block (to test how select works).  My question is, if there is nothing written to the pipe from the child, would select cause the program to hang and not reach the print statement?  If so, how is this different from not using select, and the read call just blocking?

Comment: yes. `select` is useful if you have multiple fds you're listening/writing to or you are using non-blocking IO.

Comment: @perry_VW:  If your parent process is only waiting for data from one child, there is no benefit to using `select()`.  And, as Karoly says, you aren't closing enough pipe file descriptors.  There is nowhere in the parent code that can legitimately close `r_pfd[1]`, but you won't get EOF on `r_pfd[0]` until `r_pfd[1]` is closed in the parent — as a 'for instance'.